# Avoid almost identical code duplication in double for loop with different iterators

Tags: c++

I must construct a graph from 2 different custom types **that I cannot change**.
Because their signatures and purpose are almost the same I have some code duplication I would like to remove.
Problem is they return a different iterator.

```
for (auto itFrom = m_pModelSpace->newIterator(); !itFrom->done() && nodesPassed < maxNodes; itFrom->step(), ++nodesPassed)
{
    /*
    ...
    */
    for (auto itTo = m_pModelSpace->newIterator(); itTo->objectId() != itFrom->objectId(); itTo->step())
    {
        /*
        ...
        */
    }
}

for (auto itFrom = m_pSelectionSet->newIterator(); !itFrom->done() && nodesPassed < maxNodes; itFrom->next(), ++nodesPassed)
{
    /*
    ...
    */
    for (auto itTo = m_pSelectionSet->newIterator(); itTo->objectId() != itFrom->objectId(); itTo->next())
    {
        /*
        ...
        */
    }
}
```

The comments are exactly the same code.
Is there any way to work around this?
I was thinking about a wrapper with 2 constructors for each type but then I also need a wrapper for the object iterator.
Another idea was multiple inheritance of the 2 types but that also doesn't really feel right.

Any advice?

**Summurarized solution**
Thanks to Mark B I have come to the following solution:

```
namespace {
OdDbObjectIteratorPtr get_iterator(OdSmartPtr<OdDbBlockTableRecord>& pEntityCollection)
{
    return pEntityCollection->newIterator();
}

OdDbSelectionSetIteratorPtr get_iterator(OdSmartPtr<OdSelectionSet>& pEntityCollection)
{
    return pEntityCollection->newIterator();
}

void increment_iterator(OdDbObjectIteratorPtr& iter)
{
    iter->step();
}
void increment_iterator(OdDbSelectionSetIteratorPtr& iter)
{
    iter->next();
}

}

namespace spax{
template <typename Collection>
void ConnectionGraph::ConstructGraph(Collection& pEntityCollection, int maxNodes)
{
    // ...
    for (auto itFrom = get_iterator(pEntityCollection); !itFrom->done() && nodesPassed < maxNodes; increment_iterator(itFrom), ++nodesPassed)
    {
        //...
        for (auto itTo = get_iterator(pEntityCollection); itTo->objectId() != itFrom->objectId(); increment_iterator(itTo))
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
}
```

Because the Selection set returned a parent OdSelectionSetIteratorPtr of OdDbSelectionSetIteratorPtr I added another function inspired by this solution to get the iterators.
Thanks for the help, I'm really pleased with the outcome.

Comment: Are `m_pModelSpace` and `m_pSelectionSet` of the same or different types? (using `auto` makes this really unclear) Also if they are different, do they have some common base class (or interface)?

Comment: I would assume the newIterator return type is the same for both objects ModelSpace and SelectionSet, also the return type for step() and next() are the same; if so putting the loop into a function would be the best way to go with those return types as the inputs to the function

Comment: @UnholySheep note `itFrom->step()` vs `itFrom->next()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using a template function with a level of indirection to handle the iterator increment?

```
void increment_iterator(<model space iterator type>& iter) { iter->step(); }
void increment_iterator(<selection set iterator type>& iter) { iter->next(); }

template <typename Container>
void execute_nested_loop(Container* c)
{
    for (auto itFrom = c->newIterator(); !itFrom->done() && nodesPassed < maxNodes; increment_iterator(itFrom), ++nodesPassed)
    {
        /*
        ...
        */
        for (auto itTo = c->newIterator(); itTo->objectId() != itFrom->objectId(); increment_iterator(itTo))
        {
            /*
            ...
            */
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it:

```
execute_nested_loop(m_pModelSpace);
execute_nested_loop(m_pSelectionSet);
```

Comment: This does not cope with the `step` vs `next` differences in the two loops.

Comment: I added a level of indirection to solve that problem, but the interface should really be fixed.

Comment: This looks promising, I've got a vacation day tomorrow but I'll test it Friday and I'll accept this if it works.

Comment: Had to add another function because of the special intricacies of the code but it pretty much worked perfectly and did not break any of my tests. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function with `m_pModelSpace` as parameter. In case you have to pass to match that is used in that code from local context use lambda:

```
auto advance = []( auto &it ) { it->step() };
auto loop = [&]( auto p ) {
     for (auto itFrom = p->newIterator(); !itFrom->done() && nodesPassed < maxNodes; advance( itFrom ), ++nodesPassed)
     {
        /*
         ...
        */
           for (auto itTo = p->newIterator(); itTo->objectId() != itFrom->objectId(); advance( itTo ) )
           {
               /*
                ...
               */
           }
     }
};
loop( m_pModelSpace );
advance = []( auto &it ) { it->next() };
loop( m_pSelectionSet );
```

Note: I changed lamdas parameter type to `auto` as you said that container types are unrelated. This would work for c++14 or later, otherwise you can use template.

Comment: please note the second loop uses `itFrom->next()` as opposed to `itFrom->step()`, you get my vote with that edit

Comment: I think OP specified that there is no common type `WhateverType` for both variables.

Comment: Then `auto` for parameter would work for for c++14 or template can be used.

Comment: Yeah first and second loop use a different iterator next and step method.
So this would probably only work for one of the loops.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that takes as entry the parameters that you use and where you put your identical code and call it in each loop and

Comment: Is there some reason this wouldn't work? This seems like the obvious solution.

Comment: I see this work for one loop but it seems messy for 2 loops

Comment: Why messy ? It would be exactly the same thing (the same line containing the function)

Comment: Maybe I am understanding you wrong but to make this work I would need 2 functions since it is a double for loop and the main problem stays the iterators with a different interface. Can you provide a code example?

Answer (score 1):

In C++, normalize the interfaces (get rid of `step()` vs `next()`), then use a template function.

Comment: As I said, I cannot change the interfaces.